# Symfony 2 - No route found error

Tags: php, apache, symfony, debian

I have trouble with Symfony od my new server - if I want to run Demo application, have error message in log:

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at /var/www/test/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1881 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /\" at /var/www/test/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1881, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /var/www/test/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:30)"} []
```

But when I try run local server, application on 127.0.0.1:8000 functions normally.

My config file for Apache VirtualHost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.cz
    ServerAlias domain.cz

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/web

    <Directory /var/www/test/web>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: You need to write a [route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for the `/` path. If you're trying to run the AcmeDemoBundle, make sure you've followed all the steps for installation (such as running `composer install` and `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`. Try accessing the demo bundle from `app_dev.php` instead

Comment: In production, you need to add `DirectoryIndex app.php` for the routing component to work. I didn't see that instruction on your vhost.

Comment: Route is wrote correctly. I tried all advice and no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in demo - it is not possible to deploy to production environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes from the routing. Have you declared a route in your bundles resource routing which has pattern / like this

```
bundle_homepage:
    pattern: /
    defaults: {_controller:Bundlename:Entityname:controllername}
```

Comment: Route is wrote correctly. On local server it is working correctly.

Comment: Do you have your mod_rewrite turned on in .htaccess? Have you cleared the dev/prod cache?

Comment: I have not .htaccess files. When I add RewriteEngine On to VirtualHost config file, nothing was changed